# Select top N with record from DataTable with some sorting using Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I have created a DataTable. I have populated the rows of the DataTable after some operations.

I am very new to Linq I want to Get the Top "N" Records from the DataTable implementing also some paging.

Let **dataTable** is the DataTable having some data.

I am need something like this

```
 var Query = from d in dataTable
        Order by columnName
        skip( some records pageSize * pageNumber)
        Select top N from dataTable
```

The column Name, Page size ,pageNumber and the N will passed as arguments

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(c => c.columnName)
        .Select(r => new {...})
        .Skip(10)
        .Take(5)
```

Comment: Can i do some thing like (c => "column Name"). because it need to be paramterized

Comment: To parametrize LINQ, you need build Expression.

Comment: Look at this link for that http://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/24/orderby-string-in-linq-c-net-dynamic-sorting-of-anonymous-types/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 20;
var queryResultPage = dataTable.OrderBy(c => c.columnName).Select(r => r).Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
```

Comment: The main issue is column Name. How should i pass it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var Query = dataTable.Select(o=>o).OrderBy(o=>o.columnName).Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(N);
```

**EDIT**

For pass column name you should to add this code

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

And then you could call it in this way

```
var values = dataTable.OrderByField("columnName");
```